# In Spring boot batch, should the itemWriter, itemProcessor, itemWriter be step-scoped?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch-admin

From the tutorial of [Spring Batch – Tasklets vs Chunks](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk), When define a `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, `ItemWriter`, should we give them an annotation of `@StepScope`?

Let me give a example code:

LineReader has only one instance, but it has a member `fu`. So if in multithreads env, will it cause error?

Why in this tutorial, it was not annotated by `@StepScope`?

[ChunksConfig.java](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-batch/src/main/java/com/baeldung/taskletsvschunks/config/ChunksConfig.java)

```
....
    @Bean // here is no @StepScope, but I think it should have a @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Line> itemReader() {
        return new LineReader();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step processLines(ItemReader<Line> reader, ItemProcessor<Line, Line> processor, ItemWriter<Line> writer) {
        return steps.get("processLines").<Line, Line> chunk(2)
          .reader(reader)
          .processor(processor)
          .writer(writer)
          .build();
    }
....
```

[LineReader.java](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-batch/src/main/java/com/baeldung/taskletsvschunks/chunks/LineReader.java)

```
public class LineReader implements ItemReader<Line>, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LineReader.class);
    private FileUtils fu;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        fu = new FileUtils("taskletsvschunks/input/tasklets-vs-chunks.csv");
        logger.debug("Line Reader initialized.");
    }

    @Override
    public Line read() throws Exception {
        Line line = fu.readLine();
        if (line != null) logger.debug("Read line: " + line.toString());
        return line;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        fu.closeReader();
        logger.debug("Line Reader ended.");
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: When define a ItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter, should we give them an annotation of @StepScope?

from the notes in [late-binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding)

> Any bean that uses late binding must be declared with scope="step". See Step Scope for more information. A Step bean should not be step-scoped. If late binding is needed in a step definition, the components of that step (tasklet, item reader or writer, and so on) are the ones that should be scoped instead.

Q2: if itemReader only has one instance, in multithreads env, will it cause error?

if the job is running and the reader is singleton, and you use multi-threads to read the source, it depends on how you partition the data, no issues will happen if data segregation is correct.

PS: there do have some practical limitations when using job-scoped beans in multi-threaded or partitioned steps. see the notes in [job-scope session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#job-scope)

Comment: `FileUtils fu` is shared by all instance of ItemReader If `itemReader()` is not decorated with @StepScope in this example. How it would be safe?

Comment: Did you mean you have different ItemReader to read the same file ? If so, that’s definitely not safe .  
FileUtils in this example is just a util, if use it for sharing same resource in different ItemReader, that’s not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

spring batch @bean only one time init when you start sever so if you want @bean update and init data inside body function like ItemReader,... use @StepScope

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).